# How to convert bytes to swift array

Tags: swift

I need to send an array through HTTP to my swift client but I'm not sure how to convert the bytes I've received to a swift array.

I've looked it up on google multiple times with multiple different ways of saying what I'm trying to do but all I'm getting is topics that say "convert byte array to swift string"

```swift
AF.request(exampleUrl).response { response in
    if let data = response.data, let s = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        debugPrint(s)
        let myArray = decodeSomehow(data: data)
        debugPrint(myArray[0]) // hooray
    }
}
```

I need to be able to decode arrays sent from my server but my efforts to find the solution to this problem have yielded no results.

*btw server is made with firebase functions and is run on Google frontend*
*and coded with typescript*

also to clarify I do not want to take the bytes and put them into an array, I want to decode the bytes into what they originally were on the server aka an array (originally a typescript array but if it is possible to make it a swift array that would be )

Comment: What does the data actually contain? An array of what? How is the data actually encoded?

Comment: Saying you have bytes is like saying you have characters. It tells you nothing about what language they're in, what their structure is, or what they contain.

Comment: Don’t decode or convert anything to anything. What you receive is a Data. A Data is itself an array of bytes. Just work with it directly.

Comment: `debugPrint(s)`: Does that print something? If yes, what's the output? If no, could you do `print("data: \(data as NSData)")`? And from theses output, what would you want actually in the end?

Comment: `let array = data.map { $0 }` or `for byte in data { print(byte) }`

Comment: My server is firebase. I use firebase functions

Comment: sorry for my lack of detail of what i was actually going for, hopefully you all can understand now what i meant before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do what I was trying to do...
In the end, I solved my own problem lol

all I needed to do was decode it with swiftyjson

thank you all for your answers

```
AF.request(exampleUrl).response { response in
    if let data = response.data, let s = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        let arr = JSON(data)
        debugPrint(arr)
        debugPrint(arr[0][0])
        debugPrint(s)
    }
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbowQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `Data` class is an advance version of `[UInt8]`. Normally, working directly with `Data` class is recommended. If you really want to convert it to `[UInt8]`, simply

```
let arr = [UInt8](data)
```

or

```
let arr = Array(data)
```

Comment: @matt It is. Any type followed by a `()` means initialising an instance of that type. `[UInt8]` is a type, a shorthand for `Array<UInt8>` and `[UInt8]()` is a shorthand for `Array<UInt8>()`, which is a shorthand for `Array<UInt8>.init()`. `[UInt8](sequence)` is a shorthand for `Array<UInt8>.init(sequence)`

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps... (Thanks LEO for your best Comment)

```
let string = "Hello World"
print(Array(string.utf8))
```

Comment: Much easier to simply pass the utf8 view to the initialiser `Array(string.utf8)`

Comment: or `let bytes: Array = .init(string.utf8)`